# Python says it found keywords in string that is not containing keywords

Tags: python, python-3.x

*web1*, *web2* and *web3* is three different websites I am scraping from. 
I want to see if they contain the names of `company1`, `company2` or `company3`. This worked perfectly before but is not working at the moment. `Print(matches)` returns all the companies like this `['company1', 'company2', 'company3']`. When I print web1, web2 and web3 I am able to see that they do not contain any of the names of the companies. This is the code:

```
companies = [ 'company1', 'company2', 'company3' ]

matches = [ x for x in companies if x in web1 or web2 or web3 ]

print(matches)
```

When I change matches to only one source at the time, it shows no found names of companies. The problem appears when I try to search for the names of the companies in multiple sources at the same time. 
All help is appreciated.

Comment: What is `x in web1 or web2 or web3` supposed to mean?

Comment: As @bereal hints at, your condition is not testing what you think it’s testing ... it tests if `x in web1` or `web2` is non-empty or `web3` is non-empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is slightly off, but unfortunately it still is valid Python.  The logic you intended to use was this:

```
matches = [ x for x in companies if x in web1 or x in web2 or x in web3 ]
```

That is, you want to check if a given company be in any of the three website addresses.  As you wrote it, all companies will always pass, because `web2` and `web3` will always evaluate to true.

Try this corrected version:

```
companies = [ 'company1', 'company2', 'company3' ]

web1 = 'http://www.company1.com'
web2 = 'http://www.company1.com'
web3 = 'http://www.company1.com'
matches = [ x for x in companies if x in web1 or x in web2 or x in web3 ]

print(matches)
```

This prints only:

```
['company1']
```

Note that I intentionally set all three website addresses to match only the first company, to show that only this company gets printed.

Comment: This solved it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Your boolean expression `x in web1 or web2 or web3` will always evaluate to true, because web2 evaluates to true. You could concatenate all the websites and check if x is in that:

```py
matches = [ x for x in companies if x in web1 + web2 + web3 ]
```